# How to add a calculated custom column in datagridview?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a Win Form Application.

Where i use MySql Database. I have three column - Quyntity, sold, and returned.

I want to add a new custom column on datagrid view name - available_quyntity. And it will show the result of (Quyntity - sold) + returned.

Eg - a column have Qyn - 10, Sold - 6, Returned - 2. So, the result of the available_quyntity will be 6.

How can i do this ?

Comment: So what is your issue?

Comment: Show your code. What have you done so far...!

Answer (score 0):

My Assumption is you are using DataTable to bind with you grid view.
here is a sample code that can do this task.

```
            DataTable dt = your datasource;

            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "NameForNewColumn";
            dc.DataType = typeof(WhatEverDataTypeYouWant);
            dc.Expression = "(Quyntity - sold) + returned";

            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            DataGridView.DataSource = dt;
            DataGridView.DataBind();
```